# Parseval's theorem to calculate sum - does not seem to work in this case. Why?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series

I am given that $$c_0 + \sum^{\infty}_{k=1}b_k\sin{\frac{k\pi t}{2}}$$
is the fourier series of $g(t)$ as given in this image:

[image]

I notice that the period is $T=4$, and $c_0 = 1$.

I am now asked to calculate the sum: 
$$\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}|b_k|^2.$$

Parsevals theorem states that: 
$$\frac{1}{T}\int_{period}|g(t)|^2dt = |c_0|^2 + \frac{1}{2}\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}(|a_k|^2 + |b_k|^2),$$
so in my case, with $a_k = 0, c_0 = 1, T=4$, I get: 
$$\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}|b_k|^2 = \frac{2}{4}\int_{-2}^{2}|g(t)^2| dt - 2 = \frac{2}{4}\left( \int_{-2}^{-1} 0 dt + \int_{-1}^{1}|t^2|dt + \int_{1}^{2}2^2 dt\right) - 2 = \frac{1}{3}$$

The answer is however supposed to be $\frac{4}{3}$. **Am I using Parseval's theorem wrong or what is going on?**

Comment: On $[-1,1]$, you have $g(t) = t+1$, not $= t$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I am so stupid, thank you.